# Powershell script with Restart of machine in between

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

My requirement is to add Role services in windows 2008 R2 machine.And i am using command like this

```
Import-Module ServerManager
Add-WindowsFeature "Web-Server" -Restart:$true
Write-Host "i am back after installation"
Add-WindowsFeature "Application-Server" -Restart:$true
```

But this -restart:$true is not actually re-starting the system.If this not the way how i can achieve this.Because addition of one role services expects a restart and after that only i will be able to add another role.
Please help :)

Comment: Do you get any error message from the first `Add-WindowsFeature`?

Answer (score 2):

`Add-WindowsFeature` accepts a `string[]` (array of strings) for the `-Name` parameter. You should be able to add multiple features by calling the cmdlet only once.

`Add-WindowsFeature -Name "Web-Server","Application-Server"`

Then restart the server.

Comment: This is failing with error saying needs to restart in between.